# SyntaxError: JSON.parse

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery, webmethod

I tried to call simple Web Method from JSON but I am getting errors.

In Chrome:

> SyntaxError: unexpected token <

In Firefox:

> SyntaxError: JSON.parse

Javascript code:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
     $('#<%=ddlTest.ClientID %>').change(function() {
         var value = $('#<%=ddlTest.ClientID %>').val();
         var req = $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: "Test.aspx/getTest",
             data: "{Id: '" + value + "'}",
             contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
             dataType: "json",
             success: function(data) {
                 $(alert(data.d))
             },
             error: function(XMLHttpRequest, text, error) { alert(error); },
             failure: function(response) {
                alert(response.d);
             }
         })
    });
 });
```

`.aspx` code:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlTest" AutoPostBack="false" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Value="0" Text="zero" />
    <asp:ListItem Value="1" Text="One" />
    <asp:ListItem Value="2" Text="Two" />
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:Label ID="lblTest" runat="server" Text="hiii"/>
```

WebMethod:

```
[WebMethod] 
public static string getTest(string id)
{
    return id;
}
```

Please guide me...

Comment: Your server side code won't even compile. You cannot return a value from a method declared as `void`. So the first step would be to fix and compile your server side code. Then we will see about the client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution for my problem.
I just added fool. lines into my web.config file and its working fine now.

```
<httpModules>
  <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
</httpModules>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at the response to your AJAX request in something like Firebug, you'll see HTML markup is being returned instead of JSON.

That's because your `data` parameter isn't quite right. Due to that, the request you're making doesn't match any available page methods and ends up being handled like a regular request to the ASPX page itself.

Since the first character of an HTML document is an invalid first character for a JSON document, the JSON parser will fail to parse it correctly.

To fix it, change your `data` parameter like this:

```
// Parameters to page methods are case sensitive. Id != id.
//
// Parameter names need to be quoted. ASP.NET will allow for both double and
//  single quotes, but technically only double quotes are valid JSON.
data: '{"id": "' + value + '"}",
```

Manually building JSON strings on the client-side gets messy quickly. You may be interested in [using JSON.stringify to clean that process up a bit](http://encosia.com/using-complex-types-to-make-calling-services-less-complex/).

Comment: What version of ASP.NET is this running on?

Comment: Hey Dave I got the exact problem. I just add foll. lines in web.config and its working fine.                                                      <httpModules>
      <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    </httpModules>

Answer (score -1):

remove 'return id';

instead you must serialize response to JSON and do response write

```
    using System.Text;
    using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;
    using System.IO;

...

    public static string ToJSON(this object obj)
            {
                string json = string.Empty;

                DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(obj.GetType());

                using ( MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream() )
                {
                    ser.WriteObject(ms, obj);
                    json = Encoding.Default.GetString(ms.ToArray());
                }

                return json;
            }
```

...

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(ToJSON(id));
```

Comment: Absolutely not. ASP.net takes care of the serialization, it's part of the PageMethods mechanism. You should never to that, it's doubling the work ([source](http://encosia.com/asp-net-web-services-mistake-manual-json-serialization/))

Comment: Thanks Didier, nice link ! Good to know

Comment: you are using extension method. I dont want to use extension method. If i removed 'this', it is showing an error - "Error 2 The type 'System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Runtime.Serialization, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'."

Comment: Hi Didier G, please give me the simpler way to resolve my error.